# Did someone break into Nelson & Murdock?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015

In the episode *Nelson v Murdock* (S01E10), Karen comes into the office to find Ben waiting for her. Ben says that he found the door unlocked.

As they discuss this, the camera perspective cuts to a shot from inside Matt's office, looking at Karen. The camera shakes a bit as though it's a first person POV.

No mention of this is made again in any way that I can recall, but given previous events, a break-in in the office would not be unrealistic.

**Did someone break into the office, or did Karen really just forget to lock the door? Is there any evidence (interview, etc) that this was a remnant of a dropped plot line?**

[image: Every breath you take...]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the one camera shot you describe DOES support the idea of someone watching events from within Matt's office, no further evidence or dialogue is shown that supports the idea. No further mention is made of anything missing or being out of place, nor is there any mention of the bad guys having something from the office.

> **KAREN:** How did you get in here?
>
> **BEN:** Front door.
>
> **KAREN:** You jimmied it?
>
> **BEN:** Unlocked. I keep telling you, you got to be more careful.
>
> **KAREN:** I am. No, I... I am. I was going to call you. I was out getting
>   lunch and I thought, "What the hell, I'll swing by the county clerk's
>   office and see what I can find."

Based on what we see on-screen, we are left to assume that **Karen simply left the door unlocked**.

Comment: I'll have to go back and re-watch, but I thought I remembered her saying something along the lines of, "I must have" - not actively remembering that she left it unlocked.

Comment: Actually, she never admits anything. Karen asks if he jimmied the door open. Ben says, "Unlocked. I keep telling you, you got to be more careful." "I am... No, no, I am. (pause) I was going to call you."

Comment: Yep, you're right - added a transcript of the conversation.